# How can I dynamically create a php variable in a PhpStorm live template?

Tags: php, phpstorm, live-templates

I'm trying to create a live template in PhpStorm but I'm having trouble with dynamically creating variables. I'm trying to do something like this:

```
$$VARIABLE_NAME$ = function($END$)
{

};

$this->foo(array('$VARIABLE_NAME$' => $$VARIABLE_NAME$));
```

Let's say that we type in 'bar' for the $VARIABLE_NAME$, I want to get the following result:

```
$bar = function()
{

};

$this->foo(array('bar' => $bar));
```

Basically I need a way to escape $VARIABLE_NAME$ so that it creates a php variable with the value you enter for it. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, just use `$$` for actual dollar sign.

This means that you have to replace your `$$VARIABLE_NAME$` by `$$$VARIABLE_NAME$`